# How to solve a quartic equation with $x^4$ and $x$?

Tags: quartics

I am solving some heat transfer problems, and I came across this equation:

$$(4.536 \cdot 10^{-8})x^4+ 12 x - 4316 = 0$$

The solution is $x = 320$ (I have the solutions book).

I am using a HP50g calculator that gives this same value ($320$), but I need to know how to solve it manually.

Could you help me to understand a step by step of getting to this result? Can Casio scientific calculators solve it?

Comment: There is a complicated formula for finding the roots of fourth degree polynomials - you could look it up. Are you sure you want to do this by hand? Wolfram alpha will do it online for you.

Comment: Actually, I need to know a way to do it without internet or an Hp calculator (using only Casio or manually)...

Comment: You can use Ferrari's formula for the quartic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: Are you sure the solution is $x=320$?

Comment: Do you allow numerical methods like Newton's?

Comment: @idk yes, I am sure. The solutions manual says it's 320 as well as my HP50g calculator.

Comment: Well, the solution is not $320$. $(320)^4+12(320)-4316\ne 0$

Comment: @idk Yes, the solution is right, guess you forgot the (4.536⋅10−8) term.                 ((4.536⋅10−8) x 320^4)+(12 x 320)−4316 = 0

Comment: This quartic equation can't have only one real solution.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, you are right, it has 2 real solutions. I am only interested in the positive one, because I am solving a temperature problem in Kelvin (x is the temperature).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newton's approximation, which I believe is the one used by your calculator too.

Let $f(x)=Ax^4+12x-4316$, where $A=4.536\times10^{-8}$. To approximate $x$, after sufficient iterations, you can use the recursive function below:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
Therefore you get:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{Ax_n^4+12x_n-4316}{4Ax_n^3+12}$$
After sufficient iterations, you reach $x=320.0203904...$

Comment: Thanks @John Glenn! That's the algorithm used by the calculator, you are right...

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is so small, you can use a fixed-point iteration:
$$
x_{n+1} = \frac{4316-Ax_n^4}{12}
$$
Starting with $x_0=0$ gives $x_{20} \approx 320.0203$.